# Why can not set variable value on gatling with scala?

Tags: scala, gatling

I have one scala file on gatling, I want to set global variable value and use it after, the code likes the following:

```
class TestSimulation extends Simulation {
```

init var:

```
  val users = java.lang.Double.parseDouble(System.getProperty("users"))
  val duration = java.lang.Integer.getInteger("duration")

  val host = "localhost"
  val port = 9100

  val protocol: GrpcProtocol = grpc.host(host).port(port)
```

set feeder var:

```
  val feeder: Feeder[IssueTestRequest] = Iterator.continually(
    Map(
      ("request",
        IssueTestRequest(
          biz = "demo",
          pro = "demo_test"
        )
      )
    )
  )
```

set run var:

```
  val scn = scenario("TestScn")
    .feed(feeder)
    // first function run
    .exec(
      grpc("request")
        .asyncUnaryCall(TestServiceGrpc.METHOD_ISSUE_TEST,
          "${request}")
        .check ({ response =>
          // set global value
          properties.token = response.token // HERE: save and set value
          println(properties.token) // HERE: can print my hope result
          response.result.get.code.equals(Result.Code.OK)
        })
    )
    // second function run
    .exec(
      grpc("request")
        .asyncUnaryCall(TokenServiceGrpc.METHOD_VERIFY_TEST,
          VerifyTestRequest(
            token = properties.token // HERE: use var which had set value, BUT token is empty, why??? why???
          ))
        .check({ response =>
          println(response.task.get.taskId) // I not hope result
          response.result.get.code.equals(Result.Code.OK)
        })
    )
```

run it:

```
  setUp(
    scn.inject(constantUsersPerSec(users) during (duration seconds)).protocols(protocol)
  )

}
```

Using one object save global var.

```
// global var
object properties {
  var token: String = ""
}
```

So, how should set global var? thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

It's because that's not how gatling works.

All the DSL elements are created at simulation startup, and at this point the token is indeed empty.

You need to persist the value in a session variable so that it is determined during the run